# How to add content for a subdomain created with GANDI?

Tags: dns, ubuntu-14.04, subdomain

I have a running website `http://website.net` and I want to create a *dev* subdomain and access it using `http://dev.website.net`.

I'm using http://gandi.net with a dedicated Ubuntu 14.04 server.

I created the subdomain using GANDI manager, now when I go to `http://dev.website.net` I got this:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ8ZK.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN9r2.png)

and when I use filezilla and open FTP files, I see only files for `http://website.net`, how can I add content for my *dev* subdomain? Shall I manually create a `dev` folder?